# Custom DNS mapping to azure function app url

Tags: dns, azure-functions

I have a requirement where i already have DNS url say *[www.mycustomdns.com](http://www.mycustomdns.com)*, now i have to create subdomain named *[www.qa.mycustomdns.com](http://www.qa.mycustomdns.com)*
which will point to azure function app, which is PaaS service of azure cloud, to the url *https://businessqa.azurewebsites.net* .

*My requirement*

> client ->(https://qa.mycustomdns.com)-->redirect to ->
> https://businessqa.azurewebsites.net--> Azure function

without adding any proxy or intermediate services.

So when i refered the Azure docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain

**As per the doc, we have to create CNAME entry along with TXT entry for uid.**

Will this able to fulfill my requirement or do i need to add any other interim activities or process to be brought in to support my requirement?

As i am very new to azure function and DNS mapping. Please provide suggestion on this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Clarification

First of all, I must say that respecting `contoso.com` domain is used by Microsoft Azure for examples, instead of `example.com`.

## Answer

As my domain is mycustomdns.com I will have to go to the Azure DNS zone editor where you should add the two(2) records provided by MS(Microsoft.):

1. CNAME record pointing desired location (In this case, wwww)
2. TXT record in order to verify the ownership of the domain and app with MS.

### Adding first record

```
   TYPE   NAME  TTL   VALUE
IN CNAME  www  3600  businessqa.azurewebsites.net
```

### Adding second record

```
   TYPE   NAME     TTL   VALUE
IN TXT  asuid.www  3600  <YOUR_VERIFICATION-TEXT>
```

### Steps

> Will this able to fulfill my requirement or do i need to add any other interim activities or process to be brought in to support my requirement?

**Yes**, at the server level to allow incoming connections in the desired socket (if applicable), otherwise MS will do it via an automated process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually my dns name are not hosted azure, instead of adding entry in Azure DNS Zone, can i add in another DNS server also the same cname and txt entry . Is it possible right?